# Converting a DWG/DXF to CSV or Excel

Tags: csv, autocad, dwg

I'm using ZWcad and i need to get the coordinates of hundreds of blocks into a excel sheet or .CSV file so i can import that into the GPS hardware. I know there are plenty of tools for autocad, i probably can even write one myself but as far as ZWcad goes i seem to be out of options.

However ZWcad saves to DWG too, and exports to all the other familiar cad extensions. So i was wondering if i would just save the blocks i need to export to a certain file there might be a tool/program to convert that directly into .CSV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a simple AutoLISP program demonstrating how to extract the WCS insertion point coordinates for a selection of block references to a comma-delimited CSV file.

```
(defun c:blk2csv ( / e f i p s )
    (if (and (setq s (ssget '((0 . "INSERT"))))
             (setq f (getfiled "" "" "csv" 1))
             (setq f (open f "w"))
        )
        (progn
            (repeat (setq i (sslength s))
                (setq i (1- i)
                      e (ssname s i)
                      p (trans (cdr (assoc 10 (entget e))) e 0)
                )
                (write-line (apply 'strcat (mapcar 'strcat (mapcar 'rtos p) '("," "," ""))) f)
            )
            (close f)
        )
    )
    (princ)
)
```